# Determine country of Sites Guest User (Anonymous user)

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites, locale, guest-user

We have a site built on Communities and Force.com sites.  What's the best way of determining which country a guest / anonymous user came from on a Force.com sites page?  For registered users, we can look at the Contact record, but for anonymous users, it's looking like a javascript solution.

Comment: If enough users visit your site using vpn and/or "stealth mode" types of  technology, you'll wind up collecting data that could become unreliable to where it's of no meaning to you regardless of what method you use.

Comment: Probably more appropriate for vanilla SE. Possible duplicate - [How to get visitor's location (i.e. country) using javascript geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation).

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?